# Levantar servidor con SocketIO PHP

Tags: php, socket

Estoy haciendo pruebas con SocketIO de PHP. Todo perfecto pero me surge la duda que...

En local para levantar el servidor se ejecuta un comando, pero como se hace cuando la app está alojada en un hosting compartido? se utiliza un exec de PHP o como se hace?

Espero no sea muy estúpida mi pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En teoría no debería tener ningún problema, en lo que se debe tener cuidado es en el puerto que va a utilizar SocketIO que por defecto es el 2021, el requerimiento entonces ería una IP estítica y el puerto libre y habilitado